# customizing the generated css from a wordpress plugin

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

Hi i have thie zibbra plugin ive used from the project. The plugin runs very well. My problem is how will i add customization into the generated class from a loaded plugin? heres my html code below

```
<div id="zibbra-category">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-2">
<div id="zibbra-product-14215" class="thumbnail">
<a href="http://doorbraakboeken.be/zibbra/product/14215-dorpstraat---wetstraat/">
<img src="https://cdn.zibbra.com/p/14215/1474534650.jpg?width=160&height=160" alt="Dorpstraat - Wetstraat">
</a>
<div class="caption text-center">
<h3 class="name">Dorpstraat - Wetstraat</h3>
<p class="description">In Dorpstraat - Wetstraat gaat Peter Reekmans dieper in op twee politieke niveaus en vooral de invloed van de Wetstraat op de Dorpstraat.</p>
<p class="price">€ 22,95</p>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="http://doorbraakboeken.be/zibbra/product/14215-dorpstraat---wetstraat/" role="button">View product</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

i want to customize and modify the css based into this one

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-4" >
            <div class="col-md-4">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8" >

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Any Help is muchly appreciated.TIA

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using jQuery and dom element manipulation I think. Since you are getting the html populated with id's associated with each element then you can easily grab the useful information from it. Below is a reference :

```
var prodUrl = $('#zibbra-category').find('.thumbnail a').attr('href');
var prodimgSrc = $('#zibbra-category').find('.thumbnail img').attr('src');
```

Once you get the information needed to populate just create a html string and wrap that around the existing div '#zibbra-category' to ensure it is at the right place.

After that simply hide the '#zibbra-category' div or replace it. Add your html string into the container.

One thing to keep in mind, wordpress at times does not work with '$' when you are using jQuery. it is better to use jQuery as it does not attract any conflict with other libraries in use.

Let me know if this helps. Cheers !!!

/*** Here is the code */

Below is the code. Try this.

```
  jQuery.(document).ready(function($){


    var prodUrl = $('#zibbra-category').find('.thumbnail a').attr('href');
    var prodimgSrc = $('#zibbra-category').find('.thumbnail img').attr('src'); 
    var prodDetails = $('.caption ').html();
    $( "#zibbra-category" ).wrap( "<div class='container'></div>" );
    var modifiedHtmlStr = '<div class="row"><div class="col-md-4" ><div class="col-md-4"><a href="'+prodUrl +'"><img src="'+prodimgSrc +'"/></a></div><div class="col-md-8" >'+prodDetails +'</div></div></div>';
    $( "#zibbra-category" ).parent().html(modifiedHtmlStr );
    })
```

Comment: hmmm okay havent tried this set ummm can you provide sample reference code for this? maybe this helps thanks

Comment: You want the image inside the col-md-4 ?